# Is it possible to Iframe webpage in java application, Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm stuck with this issue.
What I want is to Iframe a webpage using iframe tag and url in java application with netbeans.
so it's kind of like a browser but without and toolbar.
please help with simple code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DJ project's [JWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/index.html), which embeds the native browser in your java app. If you want a pure java solution check out the [Lobo Browser](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp). AFAIK The rendering of Lobo is not perfect(Still doesnt support CSS2 completely). As for sample code you can get full functional demos in both projects.